# MySQL create unique column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
|   Date1    |   Date2    | CompanyID |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |         1 |
| 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-02 |         1 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |         2 |
| 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-23 |         1 |
| 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-23 |         2 |
| 2017-11-21 | 2017-11-22 |         1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I want to create a table in MySQL with this data but I need to create a unique key since some of the data is the same for the two `CompanyID`s. I was thinking of combining `Date1` and `CompanyID` like this:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|     Key      |   Date1    |   Date2    | CompanyID |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-01-01-1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 |         1 |
| 2017-02-01-1 | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-02 |         1 |
| 2016-01-01-2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 |         2 |
| 2017-01-21-1 | 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-23 |         1 |
| 2017-04-10-2 | 2017-04-10 | 2017-04-11 |         2 |
| 2017-11-21-1 | 2017-11-21 | 2017-11-22 |         1 |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Is this a bad idea and why? Is there someway of linking the `Date1` + `CompanyID` to `Key` so that if `Date1` or `CompanyID` is changed it will automatically change Key?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Sorry my mistake is it actually MariaDB. Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 5.5.54-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Why do you want a unique key? To prevent some of your data from being inserted?  If so, show which data and explain why.

Comment: @ysth I want to prevent users to accidentally add duplicate data to the table. If I have a unique key for each row that wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate key column.  You can add `UNIQUE KEY (CompanyID, Date1)` to your table to prevent duplicates.  Or `PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID, Date1)` if you want it to be your primary key.

Comment: OK. Creating the table I would change PRIMARY KEY (Date1), UNIQUE (Date1) to just UNIQUE KEY (Date1, CompanyID)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea because your key will not be unique if you will have a same date and same company id more than once. Just add autoincrement key.

Comment: Is that the only draw back (each company will only put in one row for each date)?

Comment: At least for me that would be a reason to not do it this way. There can be various situations, and even if you think so, in the future you can regret that.